HTTPException always returns 200 [OK] with FastAPI
Maybe I am missing something as usual as i understand
from fastapi import FastAPI, status, HTTPException

@app.delete("/posts/{id}")
def delete_post(id: int):
    try:
        with psycopg.connect("host=localhost dbname=fastapi user=postgres password=postgres") as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                deleted_post = cur.execute("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id =  %s RETURNING *", [id]).fetchone()
                conn.commit()
                
                if deleted_post == None:
                    raise HTTPException(
                        status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                        detail=f"Post with id: {id} was not found."
                    )
                
                return {"message": deleted_post}

When I try to delete or update a non-existent id it recognizes: "if deleted_post == None:" but it always returns status 200 OK

Does it return the detail text you have specified? What if you return the exception instead of raiseing it?

You have all of that code inside a try block, but you didn't show the expect block. My guess is that the exception is returned as arbitrary JSON in your expect block, and that is why the status code has no effect.

thank you blek__ now it works:
@app.delete("/posts/{id}")
def delete_post(id: int):
    try:
        with psycopg.connect("host=localhost dbname=fastapi user=postgres password=postgres ") as conn:
            with conn.cursor() as cur:
                deleted_post = cur.execute("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id =  %s RETURNING *", [id]).fetchone()
                conn.commit()
                print(deleted_post)
                
                if deleted_post != None:
                    return {"message": deleted_post}
            
    except Exception as error:
        return {"message": error}
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
        detail=f"Post with id: {id} was not found."
    )

